# Excel Inputbox Function with conditions

Tags: excel, inputbox, vba

Background info:

- Column A = Last Names,
- Column B = First Names,
- Column C = a drop down box with a list of options determining whether
  the person listed in A1B1 has a certain status(active rep,
  disaffiliated, etc) there are 5 or 6

In column D, I would like an input box to prompt the user depending on what the answer choice is in Column C. If for example `'C2' = "Active Rep"`, I'd like the prompt to ask for a date `mmddyy`, or if they hit cancel to allow them to enter something manually (text)

If `'C2' = Disaffiliated`, I would like to to provide a drop down box giving them a list of options from the control page.

This would need to happen for each named person in Column A for which there are about 100

Is this possible or am I thinking too big and just need to simplify things.

Comment: `Is this possible or am I thinking too big`? What do you think?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `WorkSheet_Change()` event to check what was input and do a `Select Case` statement to handle each selection differently.